# Is there a Bitcoin Cash explorer that supports Xpub addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, xpub

As the title says... I've been unable to find a block explorer that supports Xpub for Bitcoin Cash(BCH). Does anyone know of any? In particular and preferably, one that will allow for fetching via `GET` (so I can import the data into a Google Spreadsheet).

Answer (score 2):

[Blockonomics](https://bch.blockonomics.co) supports lookup of xpubs and multiple addresses. They recently [announced support](https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/denyf1/bch_is_now_live_on_blockonomics/) for BCH

Answer (score 1):

Blockbook has direct support for Xpub lookup. There are two ways you can go about using it. You can look up the Xpub directly through the regular web frontend by copying/pasting it into the search field up top.

The second way is to use the api endpoint:

```
/api/v2/xpub/xpubaddr
```

This returns a json response containing the wallet balance across all the addresses for this Xpub as well as txids and the addresses themselves depending on parameters you supply. See https://github.com/trezor/blockbook/blob/master/docs/api.md#get-xpub for details.

There are quite a few blockbook-based bch explorers out there. Here's a non-exhaustive list:

- bch1.trezor.io (goes up to 5; Also, status.trezor.io provides uptime status)
- bch.nownodes.io (you'll need to register for free api-key)
- bchbook.guarda.co
- bchblockexplorer.com
- bch1.blockbook.bitaccess.net
- blockbook-bcash.binancechain.io
- bcash.blockbook.chains.klever.io
- bitcoin-cash-node.atomicwallet.io

Answer (score 0):

This might help- you can run SQL queries on massive amounts of Bitcoin Cash blockchain data with the scale of Google BigQuery. The ETL system is already built, there are no limitations or specific requests required, and Google offers additional API support through their client libraries https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/cmorqs-public/cmorq-bch-data This solution provides a sample of the data, but you can get access to the full live data set through the company website.

Comment: Thanks but when I go to that link it just says “failed to load“

Answer (score -1):

I just found this app. Looks good but it's quite new so maybe give it a try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valcourgames.walletwatch.android

Comment: Thanks but that's not a web based block explorer... I need one I can incorporate into a spreadsheet.